# PHP remove array in array by using another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. The first is my array and the second is the API response :

```
$array1 = [
    ["id" => 45, "name" => "toto"],
    ["id" => 50, "name" => "tata"],
    ["id" => 31, "name" => "titi"],
    ["id" => 82, "name" => "tutu"],
    ["id" => 12, "name" => "tototo"]
];

$array2 = [
    "45" => ["status" => false], 
    "50" => ["status" => true], 
    "31" => ["status" => true],
    "82" => ["status" => false],
    "12" => ["status" => true]
];
```

I'd like to remove in `array1` all `id` in `array2` who have a status `false`, or keep all `id` with status `true`

In this example I need to get :

```
$array1 = [
    ["id" => 50, "name" => "tata"],
    ["id" => 31, "name" => "titi"],
    ["id" => 12, "name" => "tototo"]
];
```

Because `id` `45` and `82` are false in the second array, then I remove them from the first array.

How I can do that without using multiple loops ? There is a solution if we play with php functions like `array_diff` or something like this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the `$array1`. Return true if `id` exist and status is true.

```
$array1 = ...
$array2 = ...

$result = array_filter($array1, function( $o ) use( $array2 ) {
    return isset( $array2[ $o["id"] ] ) && $array2[ $o["id"] ]["status"];
});
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50
            [name] => tata
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [name] => titi
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => tototo
        )

)
```

Comment: This is the more appropriated response

Answer (score 1):

The most readable solution is often better than using fancy `array_*` functions, i.e. in this case a simple `foreach` loop is sufficient:

https://3v4l.org/5eNEf

```
<?php

$array1 = [
    ["id" => 45, "name" => "toto"],
    ["id" => 50, "name" => "tata"],
    ["id" => 31, "name" => "titi"],
    ["id" => 82, "name" => "tutu"],
    ["id" => 12, "name" => "tototo"]
];

$array2 = [
    "45" => ["status" => false], 
    "50" => ["status" => true], 
    "31" => ["status" => true],
    "82" => ["status" => false],
    "12" => ["status" => true]
];

$result = [];
foreach($array1 as $arrayEl) {
    $id = $arrayEl['id'];

    if($array2[$id]['status'] === true) {
        $result[] = $arrayEl;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

*Note: We are not modifying the original content but create a new result array. You might want to add additional `isset` checks depending on what keys your array contains/might not contain.*

Comment: Why not using unset instead of create a new array ? We get better performance if we create ?

Comment: @John Hi, you can read up on mutability/immutability principles here https://medium.freecodecamp.org/write-safer-and-cleaner-code-by-leveraging-the-power-of-immutability-7862df04b7b6 TL;DR you want to prevent side-effects in your code thus you try to avoid mutating existing data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
<?php
$array1 = [
    ["id" => 45, "name" => "toto"],
    ["id" => 50, "name" => "tata"],
    ["id" => 31, "name" => "titi"],
    ["id" => 82, "name" => "tutu"],
    ["id" => 12, "name" => "tototo"]
];

$array2 = [
    "45" => ["status" => false], 
    "50" => ["status" => true], 
    "31" => ["status" => true],
    "82" => ["status" => false],
    "12" => ["status" => true]
];

foreach($array1 AS $key => $value){
    if(!$array2[$value['id']]['status']){
        unset($array1[$key]);
    }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);

?>
```

Find the key from first array and unset it using the true or false value.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50
            [name] => tata
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [name] => titi
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => tototo
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk`

```
$res=[];
array_walk($array1, function(&$v,$k) use (&$res,$array2){
  ($array2[$v['id']]['status'] == 1) ? ($res[] = $v): '';
});
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZEC1D)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution for the same,

```
array_walk($array1, function(&$item,$key) use(&$array1, $array2){
    if(!$array2[$item['id']]['status'])  // checking status if false
        unset($array1[array_search($item['id'], array_column($array1,'id'))]); // then unset
});
print_r($array1);
```

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array
[array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b699f5d4200399dbef98ff779e3e4c57479722b).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the least readable solution :-)

Array_intersect and array_column can also get the job done.

I make both arrays associative on id then use array_intersect_key to get the true values.

```
// Make $array1 associative.
$array1 = array_column($array1, null, "id");

// Find all true values in $array1 from $array2
$result = array_intersect_key($array1, array_intersect(array_combine(array_keys($array2), array_column($array2, "status")), [true]));
```

https://3v4l.org/QVoI5

Answer (score -1):

```
$array1 = [
    ["id" => 45, "name" => "toto"],
    ["id" => 50, "name" => "tata"],
    ["id" => 31, "name" => "titi"],
    ["id" => 82, "name" => "tutu"],
    ["id" => 12, "name" => "tototo"]
];

$array2 = [
    "45" => ["status" => false],
    "50" => ["status" => true],
    "31" => ["status" => true],
    "82" => ["status" => false],
    "12" => ["status" => true]
];

foreach ($array1 as $tocheck) {

    if ($array2[$tocheck['id']]['status']) {
        $new[] = $tocheck;
    }
}

print_r($new);
```